# interrupt pin of attiny85 unstable

Tags: interrupt, attiny, pull-up, atmel

I'm trying to learn how to program a MC, so maybe I didn't know much about a MC. I tried to test interrupt pin of ATtiny85 with this simple code

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void setup()
{
  GIMSK = 0b00100000;
  PCMSK = 0b00000001;
  sei();
  DDRB = 0b00010000;
}

void loop()
{
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(500);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(500);
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00010000;
  _delay_ms(100);
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  _delay_ms(100);

}
```

This is just a blink code with an interrupt to make the LED blink faster 10 times. My question is why sometimes the LED blink faster many times with the interrupt pin is not connected to anything (open)? Didn't it have internal pull up or should I use external pull up in my circuit?

Thank you

Comment: You only get an internal pullup if you actively turn that internal pullup on.

Comment: @Majenko so how to enabling internal pullup with use it as interrupt pin too? is it possible?

Comment: The interrupt functionality is completely separate to the IO functionality. Make sure the pin is an INPUT and set it HIGH will turn on the pullup. You need to know which DDR and PORT for the pin you're using as an interrupt of course.

Comment: You really shouldn’t have interrupts that take multiple *seconds* to finish executing. Interrupts should finish quickly so your main program can get back to its processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than an answer, these are some comments and suggestions on your
program, that I hope will help you write cleaner code:

1. Since you seem to be avoiding using the Arduino core library, you may
   as well write your own `main()` instead of relying on the one from
   the core. This way you have a plain C program that can be compiled
   either within or outside of the Arduino framework.
2. Instead of opaque constants, like `0b00100000`, use the bit names.
   These names are defined in the datasheet and are provided by the
   avr-libc. They are normally used with the `_BV()` macro, which
   expands to `(1<<(x))`.
3. For those of us who do not have the full datasheet in our head, a
   comment or two stating what each bit does is helpful.
4. To change only one bit from a port, use the syntax `PORTB |= ...;`
   or `PORTB &= ...`. The compiler is smart enough to turn this into
   single assembly instructions, namely `sbi` and `cbi`.
5. Rather than repeating ten times the same lines, use a loop.

Applying these suggestions, your program would like like;

```c++
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        PORTB |= _BV(PB4);
        _delay_ms(100);
        PORTB &= ~_BV(PB4);
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    PORTB = _BV(PB0);     // internal pullup on PB0
    GIMSK = _BV(PCIE);    // enable pin change interrupt
    PCMSK = _BV(PCINT0);  // sense pin change on PCINT0 = PB0
    DDRB  = _BV(PB4);     // pin PB4 as output
    for (;;) {
        PORTB |= _BV(PB4);
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB &= ~_BV(PB4);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much this is very helpful. This is very useful for beginners. And what's the double semicolon for? Is it like while(1)? Since there are so many tutorials with Arduino library, it's pretty difficult to find some code examples with plain C program (or not?)

Comment: The `for(;;)` is an infinite loop, just like `while(1)`.

Comment: Did this code solve your problem with the double execution, that you mentioned below?

Comment: @juliussin: As stated by @chrisl, `for (;;)` introduces an infinite loop. I prefer it over `while (true)` because it feels natural to me to read it like “for (ever)”.

Comment: @chrisl I just tried this code, and this code didn't  solve the double ISR if I connect the interrupt pin to the ground with a jumper (I use breadboard to place my ATtiny85) and the repeated ISR if I touch the jumper pin. And unfortunately I doesn't have scope to check the signal of the interrupt pin :(

Comment: Is it because a bounce like on tactile push button? Just my opinion btw

Comment: I thought about this, but your ISR is way longer that any bounce from the button should be. During the ISR no other interrupt of the same kind can be queued, I think

Answer (score 1):

The internal pullup is only activated, if you activate it in your code. To so, you have to write a `1` to the corresponding bit in the `PORTB` register, while the `DDRB` register is set for the pin to be an input.

So you the interrupt gets triggered randomly, because the pin was floating.

Since you are currently always write to the whole `PORTB`, you have to change the last bit to `1` on every `PORTB` write. Or you can write a `1` to it in `setup()` and only change the one output bit in `PORTB` by using

```
PORTB ^= 0b00010000;
```

This will toggle only your output pin.

Comment: Wow thank you, I'm using PORTB because I want to learn how register work and avoid to depend on library. So based on your suggestion I changed the last bit to 1 on every PORTB I wrote. I think this is worked pretty good. But if I touch the interrupt pin with my hand, the ISR run repeated. Is this because the trigger is unstable if I touch it?

Comment: This should not happen, if you activated the internal pullup resistor. I tried this with my ATTiny85 and it works perfectly.

Comment: I activated the internal pullup as you said by changed the last bit to 1 on every PORTB I wrote. But with the human touch, it's still unstable. And another problem, If i connect the interrupt pin to VCC, nothing happened (because it is pulled up right?) but if i connect it to GND, it run ISR twice, and then I release it, it run ISR once.

Comment: Odd behavior (that with the double execution). I couldn't reproduce that on my hardware. Maybe there is something odd with your wiring.